# Clarification on the Snowflake Micro Partition Size?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need the clarification on the size of Snowflake's Micro partition size. In the snowflake official document, It is mentioned as below.

> Each micro-partition contains between 50 MB and 500 MB of uncompressed data (note that the actual size in Snowflake is smaller because data is always stored compressed).

However in some places i see below statement on the micro partition size.

> Snowflake also stores multiple rows together in micro-partitions, which are variable-length data blocks of around 16 Mb size

What is the size of the data that Micro-partition can hold 16 MB or (50 -500 MB), or else does each Micro-partition has data block which is of 16 MB?

Comment: The size of the partition's shouldn't matter. What is the question you are trying to answer that you think the micro partition size is impacting?

Comment: Hello Simeon - if the size of partition shouldn't matter than why is the restriction on 16 MB limitation for variant column, can you please share your thought on this?

Comment: These are completely unrelated details. 16MB variant column restriction is because if you have a more than 1-2MB of variant data it is super unlikely to be a single object, and more likely to be a nested/array construct. Thus you should pull that object apart into individual rows. Again if your variant is larger that 1-2MB it starts to seems like it is a file or binary blob, and databases are not that place to store files, a file system is. So basically the 16MB limit is the hint that you are doing you data processing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The key point is **compression**:

[Benefits of Micro-partitioning](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html#benefits-of-micro-partitioning)

> As the name suggests, micro-partitions are small in size **(50 to 500 MB, before compression)**, which enables extremely efficient DML and fine-grained pruning for faster queries.
>
> **Columns are also compressed individually within micro-partitions. Snowflake automatically determines the most efficient compression algorithm for the columns in each micro-partition.**

The size of 50-500MB is for **uncompressed data** and micropartition itself holds around 16MB(after compression).

Comment: Thanks @Lukasz. Does it mean 50-500 MB compressed to 16 MB of data ?Also as an Add on question - Why does snowflake restrict in even loading 16 MB  uncompressed objects to a variant column.